# creating rss with using scrapy

Tags: python, rss, scrapy, pipeline

I added a pipeline which I found as an answer in stackoverflow to a sample project. 
it is :

```
import csv
from craiglist_sample import settings


def write_to_csv(item):
   writer = csv.writer(open(settings.csv_file_path, 'a'), lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow([item[key] for key in item.keys()])



class WriteToCsv(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        write_to_csv(item)
        return item
```

it writes correctly to a csv file. then I change it to this one :

```
import csv
import sys
from craiglist_sample import settings
import datetime
import PyRSS2Gen

def write_to_csv(item):

    rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
        title = "Andrew's PyRSS2Gen feed",
        link = "http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html",
        description = "The latest news about PyRSS2Gen, a "
                      "Python library for generating RSS2 feeds",

        lastBuildDate = datetime.datetime.now(),

        items = [
           PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
             title =str((item['title']),
             link = str((item['link']),
             description = "Dalke Scientific today announced PyRSS2Gen-0.0, "
                           "a library for generating RSS feeds for Python.  ",
             guid = PyRSS2Gen.Guid("http://www.dalkescientific.com/news/"
                              "030906-PyRSS2Gen.html"),
             pubDate = datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 6, 21, 31)),

        ])

    rss.write_xml(open("pyrss2gen.xml", "w"))

class WriteToCsv(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        write_to_csv(item)
        return item
```

But problem is it writes only the last entry to the xml file. How can I fix this? do I need to add new line for each entry?

items.py is :

```
class CraiglistSampleItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title=Field()
    link=Field()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `a` to append, your are overwriting each time using `w` so you only get the last piece of data:

```
rss.write_xml(open("pyrss2gen.xml", "a"))
```

If you look at the original code you can that also uses `a` not `w`.

You might want to use [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) when opening files or at least closing them.

Comment: thanks. it creates title for all entry now . I mean like this http://i.imgur.com/OO5n1Of.jpg  .    is it possible to write under one title ? http://i.imgur.com/LKUdVUI.jpg  .

Comment: I try creating a rsss.py in that folder which has   rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(title='ff',link='',description='',lastBuildDate='',items = [])     . my intention was achieving this rss variable from outside and append items to it. after it finishes adding I was going to write to xml but couldnt use this rss variable as a global variable

Comment: It adds all items that was scrapped but I guess the rss is not valid because it has multiple title. this  isnt about your answer though, thanks again